# How can I reduce the vibration noise in new corrugated tubing connected to my sump pump?

Tags: sump-pump

My sump pump recently went bad and while replacing it, I also decided to replace the plastic corrugated tubing that was connected to it.

When I turned on the new pump, the amount of noise it was making sounded like there was an elephant in the basement.  Best I could tell, that noise came from the corrugated tubing getting into some resonating vibration.  After wiggling things here and there, I removed the new tubing and put the old one back in and now the pump is as quiet as a mouse.

As far as I know, this is a standard corrugated tubing for use with sump pumps that I bought from the local hardware store. But it appears to be made of a slightly harder plastic than the old tubing and I think that is partially why vibration noise is so much higher.

Is there anything that can be done to eliminate the noise besides having to use really old tubing which I would like to replace at some point?

Comment: `natural frequency = sqrt(k/m)` where `k` is the stiffness and `m` is mass. So if the old tubing wasn't vibrating, increasing the mass on the newer stiffer tubing should lower the natural frequency back down to where it was before.

Answer (score 1):

You might try insulating a section of the pipe with foam insulation.Then try to mount that to something solid like a section of 2x4.

Comment: You can also try isolating the sump pump from the plastic pipe with a section of rubber pipe of the proper diameter; a hose clamp and some sealant on either side of a short length will absorb some vibration that would otherwise be transmitted directly from the pump housing into the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the corrugated tubing with smooth black plastic pipe in the same size as your corrugated pipe.   It bends slightly, but you will also probably need a 90 degree elbow to make the turn from "up" to "out".   Although it fits on the connectors pretty snugly, be sure to get hose clamps for all of the connections; it would be a bad day if one of the connections eventually came apart.